# How to get values of DisplayField from Form Extjs 6.0.2?

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs6-classic

I am trying to get the values of **dispalyfield** from form using **this.up('form').getValues()** . But i am getting as empty object.

Can someone help me on this? Extjs version 6.0.2

Here Sample Code I tried:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 175,
    height: 150,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Final Score',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Home',
        name: 'home_score',
        value: '10'
    }, {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Visitor',
        name: 'visitor_score',
        value: '11'
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Update',
        handler: function (button, e) {
            var form = this.up('form');
            var values = form.getValues();

            Ext.log({
                msg: "values: ",
                values
            });

            Ext.log({
                msg: "Home: " + values.home_score
            });

            Ext.log({
                msg: "Visitor: " + values.visitor_score
            });

        }
    }]
});
```

Note: **Display Field** ----- **Ext.getCmp("someID").getValue()** I tried and getting the value. But I want to get and set values of **dispalyfield** from form without getCmp and ID.

Comment: How are you setting the value? The value never changes, so get it from there.

Comment: @Evan you can see the displayfield, i am setting the value while creating the field

Comment: Yep, that is my point.

Comment: Yeah, But the form.getValues() is returning the value object for "textfield" but not for "displayfield". If i change the xtype to "textfield" i am getting the value. But i want the field as displayfield.

Comment: Docs:
"A display-only text field which is not validated and not submitted. This is useful for when you want to display a value from a form's loaded data but do not want to allow the user to edit or submit that value."
Link(at the beginning):
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Display.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to use [`form.getForm()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#method-getForm) it will return the `Ext.form.Basic` form. Now you need to use [`getFieldValues()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-getFieldValues) for getting the values and [`setValues()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-setValues) for setting values of fields.

In this **[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2k8a)**, I have created an demo using above method.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 175,
            height: 150,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            title: 'Final Score',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Home',
                name: 'home_score',
                value: '10'
            }, {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Visitor',
                name: 'visitor_score',
                value: '11'
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Update',
                handler: function (button, e) {
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm(),
                        values = form.getFieldValues();

                    Ext.log({
                        msg: "values: " + Ext.encode(values)
                    });

                    Ext.log({
                        msg: "Home: " + values.home_score
                    });

                    Ext.log({
                        msg: "Visitor: " + values.visitor_score
                    });

                    form.setValues({
                        home_score: 100,
                        visitor_score: 111
                    });
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```